# Safe Area changes in parent VC when presenting modally VC in landscape

Tags: ios, ios11, landscape, landscape-portrait, safearealayoutguide

Safe Area Insets in first UIViewController changes to Safe Area Inset for landscape when I present SecondViewController, which supports only landscape orientation.

[GIF with described bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDn6E.gif)

[GIF with described bug that touches TabBar and TableView](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14925971/32981615-e8cd5a74-cc88-11e7-9a34-43c00f6452e6.gif)

FirstViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBAction func showSecondVC(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")

    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: {
      print("completed")
    })
  }

  override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    print(view.safeAreaInsets)
    super.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()
    print(view.safeAreaInsets)
  }
}
```

Second ViewController:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
  override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return [.landscape]
  }

  @IBAction func dismissYourSelff(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Console output:

```
UIEdgeInsets(top: 44.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 34.0, right: 0.0)
UIEdgeInsets(top: 44.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 34.0, right: 0.0)
UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 44.0, bottom: 21.0, right: 44.0)
UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 44.0, bottom: 21.0, right: 44.0)
completed
```

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @MrJre check my answer below. I fixed it with showing a snapshot during presentation and removing it afterwards. Only for iPhone X devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how I solved the problem with constraints: 
https://gist.github.com/filletofish/b56600e9e661aa6e49cc0a56a98b37a3

I had to use snapshots to prevent wrong layout of TabBar and TableView.

```
override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    var completionToRemoveSnapshot: (() -> ())? = nil

    let shouldUseSnapshot = SDiOSVersion.deviceSize() == .Screen5Dot8inch &&
      viewControllerToPresent.supportedInterfaceOrientations == .landscape

    if shouldUseSnapshot {
      if let snapShot = self.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) {
        viewController.view.addSubview(snapShot)
        completionToRemoveSnapshot = { snapShot.removeFromSuperview() }
      }
    }

    super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: {
      completionToRemoveSnapshot?()
      completion?()
    })
  }
```